# Set of class type

Tags: c++, stl

Can you write a overloaded function to remove the DATA object from set by for example: `s.erase(4)` Here `4` can be the value or x or y.

```
struct DATA
{
   DATA(int X, int Y):x(X), y(Y){}
   int x;
   int y;

   bool operator < (const DATA &d) const
   {
       return x < d.x || (x == d.x && y < d.y);
   }
};


int main()
{
   set <DATA> s;

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      s.insert(DATA(i, i+5));

   s.erase(0) // remove where x = 0
}
```

Comment: can't you simply overload the "operator==" ?

Answer (score 2):

Sure!

You could write a functor to search for set elements where EITHER x or y are 4, and erase such elements. You'll want `boost::bind` to make the binding easier:

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

struct Foo {
    int x, y;

    bool operator<(const Foo& rhs) const {
        return (x < rhs.x || (x == rhs.x && y < rhs.y));
    }

    bool hasValue(int v) const {
        return (x == v || y == v);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<Foo> s;
    Foo a = {4,2}; s.insert(a);
    Foo b = {3,4}; s.insert(b);

    std::cout << s.size() << std::endl; // will output: "2"

    std::set<Foo>::iterator it;

    // Search for an element with the given value '4' in either x or y
    // Erase first matching element found, if any
    // (our first element, which has x=4)
    it = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), boost::bind(&Foo::hasValue, _1, 4));
    if (it != s.end())
        s.erase(it);

    std::cout << s.size() << std::endl; // will output: "1"

    // Erase the next one
    // (our second element, which has y=4)
    it = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), boost::bind(&Foo::hasValue, _1, 4));
    if (it != s.end())
        s.erase(it);

    std::cout << s.size() << std::endl; // will output: "0"
}
```

Has not been tested extensively for typos.

You can get the same functionality without boost, using a static member function that takes a `Foo*` as an argument.

Comment: Yes, you could iterate over the whole thing, but you don't get the performance characteristics of the set (your search and remove takes O(n^2 lg n) time while one would want a set to take O(lg n) time). Better yet, use a handwritten loop that tags all of the elements you want to remove and remove them all at once (as indicated in my answer) which drops the total time to O(n lg n).

Comment: As for losing the performance characteristics of the set, that's inherent in the OP's requirement. To be honest, IMO, wanting to do this in the first place is a bit of a code smell.

Comment: Think I would recommend using a `std::multimap<int,int>` here instead. What do you think, Billy?

Comment: @Tomalak: multimap stores multiple items per key, not multiple keys per item.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Sorry, thinking of `boost::bimap` actually. He wants map behaviour, and he wants to index in either direction.

Answer (score 2):

Use [boost::multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Here is a [description on how to do a multiindex set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort).

Answer (score 0):

No; your set is ordered by X, you cannot also order the set by Y in order to remove by it. You would need to iterate through the set to find items you want to remove, then remove them as you would normally remove from the set.

Comment: No, his set is ordered by `x` *and* `y`. See his comparator function.

Comment: (Indeed, the "problem" is that he cannot selectively index on one or the other; they are inextricably linked as a pair of values.)

Comment: @Tomalak: y is a secondary key -- the set is indexed by x and y is used to break ties. You can look up the primary key (x), but you can't look up by secondary (at least, not with a single set structure).

Comment: How would he go about looking up on `x` using `std::set`'s mechanisms? The container has key near-equivalent to `std::pair<int,int>`, not `int`.

Comment: @Tomalak: Find Data(WantedXValue, 0) and Data(WantedXValue + 1, 0) (which gives you the range of items which have that X value) in `lg n` time.

Comment: Hang on, surely that breaks if those elements are not found. Finding elements in sets is exact-match, hence the requirement for Strict Weak Ordering. If either `Data(WantedXValue,0)` or `Data(WantedXValue+1,0)` are not found, then he will have `set.end()` in the wrong place and his range will be broken.

Comment: @Tomalak: Use `std::set::lower_bound` instead of `find`. Of course you have to check if `end` is returned or if the two returned iterators are equal. But it's still possible to look up by the first key in `lg n` time.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Yup, that'd do it. Good approach, but still think the use of `std::set` at all is non-idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Sure- you can modify the Data structure to operate on a larger integral type and use bit-shifting to pack a pair of smaller integral types in. However, in a more generic sense, then no. There are containers that are multiple index, but std::set is not one of them.

Comment: I'm not really sure how merging to a larger integral type is going to help searching for a partial value in a std::set. Anyway, even if that were possible, I don't think you should give beginners ideas on how to obfuscate their code to oblivion... :)

Answer (score 0):

How about `std::map` container? You could either use x or y as a key_type and keep the non-key values in class as value_type.

Comment: Or `boost::bimap` to use either value as key whenever you choose.